# Select Nokogiri element after an element with particular attribute

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have been at this for hours and I cannot make any progress.
I do not know how to do the following, I am used to arrays and loops, not nokogiri objects.

I want to select the table element immediately after the h2 containing span with id == "filmography"

```
<h2><span id ="filmography>...
<table>  # What I want to find
  <tr>
    <td>...
```

So far I have used

```
objects = page.xpath("//h2" | "//table")
```

to have an array of nokogiri objects and I test each for id == "Filmography" and would work with the next object, however the elements returned are not in order as they appear on the page they are in the order all h2's then all tables.

Could I somehow have all 'h2's and 'table's as element objects in the order they appear on the page, and test the child object 'span' for its id attribute?

All advice appreciated, as I am thoroughly stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like it should work:

```
page.xpath('h2//span[@id="filmography"]').first.next_element
```

Comment: Thanks, that would select all the h2 elements I want, however it would be the table element on the page directly after the h2 that I want. Can I fill an array of elements with h2 tags and table tags in the order they are on the page?

For example I would select the next sibling element after identifying the h2 I want.

Comment: If the "table" element follows immediately, you should be able to get it with Nokogiri::XML::Node#next_element.  Editing to suggest that.

Comment: I believe that I want to select a single element, the next sibling of the parent of the element that your code would select. So I need to go to the parent node, then sibling. h2 is the same level as table, span is a child of h2

Comment: h2 = page.xpath('h2//span[@id="Filmography"]/..')

This seems to select the h2 I want, I am trying to include .next_element . The item h2 evaluates as a nodeset if that is ok.

Comment: Try `NodeSet#first` to pick out your node?

Comment: h2 = page.xpath('h2//span[@id="Filmography"]/..').first.next_element


 - works, thanks Wolff!

Answer (score 1):

Nokogiri supports CSS selectors, which make this easy:

```
doc.at('span#filmography table').to_html
=> "<table><tr>\n<td>...</td>\n    </tr></table>"

doc.at('#filmography table').to_html
=> "<table><tr>\n<td>...</td>\n    </tr></table>"
```

[`at`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#method-i-at) returns the first matching node, using either a CSS or XPath selector.

The "NodeSet" equivalent is `search`, which returns a NodeSet, which is like an Array, but would force you to use `first` after it, which only really makes for a longer command:

```
doc.search('span#filmography table').first.to_html
doc.search('#filmography table').first.to_html
```

Because the `span` tag contains an `id` parameter, you're safe to use `at` and only look for `#filmography`, since IDs are unique in a page.